# Why is source code generated by WordPress that ugly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few pages, all running on WordPress. When I look into sourcecode of them, everyone but one seems quite nice - clean. But source code of one of them looks really bad, there are no newlines, indents, whitespaces at all. There are also missing lines of codes, however site works like it should have work.

All sites run on the same version of WordPress, they have simillar plugins installed.

It is not burning issue, just out of curiosity, have you any ideas why it is like that?

Comment: Because nobody cares enough to make it otherwise, probably.

Comment: It doesn't manner how your markup is indented—it wouldn't influence how the page is parsed.

Answer (score 5):

Because tidy code and whitespace are for **developers, not computers**: I make my code tidy and use lots of nice newlines and tabs to make it easier for myself and my colleagues to read.

A computer, though, doesn't care - and all those spaces and lines are extra data to transmit. If you take all that whitespace away, you can save quite a large proportion of your bandwidth.

For example imagine the following lines in the middle of a code block. This kind of thing is very common when closing a class or function

```
                } //if
            } //if
        } //while
    } // function
} //class
```

Ignoring the comments (which I've added to show how easily it can happen) and that's 40 spaces and 4 newlines... for 5 braces. That's a total of 49 characters when I only actually wanted 5. What a waste! Okay, so 44 extra characters doesn't sound like a lot... but when I've got thousands of lines with these indents, it adds up.

Similarly compare the following (33 chars)

```
if(a=1){return a;}else{return b;}
```

With a readable version (52 chars)

```
if ( a = 1 )
{
    return a;
}
else
{
    return b;
}
```

That's 12 extra spaces plus 7 extra newlines, bringing us up to 52 characters which not far off double - on a tiny, very simple code sample. While these are simple examples, it can get much more extreme when you get to 6 or 7 levels of indentation as shown in the previous example

This is a process called [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and can be as simple as removing whitespace, or can go further and compress variable/function/class names etc to reduce the file size even further. My assumption is that the wordpress site you've seen is using some kind of minification plugin either as part of Wordpress (most likely), or in the webserver itself or a cache/similar.

Comment: It doesn't even matter in PHP files, they're not getting transmitted anywhere. There is not much of a point to minify them. Also, I'm quite unsure if OP meant html markup or actual source code.

Comment: Well it can make a very slight difference to interpretation time, but nothing you'd care about. The way the question was phrased, however, very much suggests the OP is looking at the resultant source code, rather than the backend PHP Wordpress files. That option makes **much** more sense (being pretty common) than the idea they have a minified Wordpress install itself (which I've literally never heard of happening)

Comment: Yeah, I know about everything you said. The thing is that I have header.php code:
`...
<script>
  //script code
</script>
...`
that is working but isn't visible in page source code.

Comment: Has that code been offloaded into a single-file javascript file? Some minifiers will combine all the Javascript into a single JS file, all the CSS into a single CSS file.

Comment: You just said it's not visible in the source code, though? So I'm asking if the minifier could have **moved** it from being inline to being in a single file with all the other JS, considering it's apparently still working despite not being visible...

Comment: It is of course visible in source code in file header.php but it is not visible in source code from view-sorce:...

Comment: I understand that, that's why I've already asked the following: have you checked for an external JavaScript file in the source code, or somewhere else in the code? Some minifiers will *move* your JavaScript. Particularly to the bottom of the page so it loads after the rest of the page